# SQL Query ISNULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I have four fields A,B,C,D
I need SQL query to show results only when two or more fields are not null

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres you can use:

```
select *
from the_table
where num_nonnulls(a,b,c,d) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want ANSI SQL which would work with any SQL database, you would need to use a case expression. It gets a bit cumbersome because case is pretty wordy, but is relatively straightforward:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    mytable
where 
   case when a is null then 0 else 1 end 
 + case when b is null then 0 else 1 end 
 + case when c is null then 0 else 1 end 
 + case when d is null then 0 else 1 end 
 >= 2;
```